# Why did the Mughals call themselves "Gurkani" when Babur himself was a direct descendant of Genghis Khan?

Tags: india, mongol-empire, mughals, central-asia, mongols

According to the [Wikipedia article on the Timurid dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timurid_dynasty):

> The Timurid dynasty called themselves "Gurkani". The word "Gurkani" derives from "Gurkan", a Persianized form of the Mongolian word "Kuragan" meaning "son-in-law". This was an honorific title used by the dynasty as the Timurids were in-laws of the line of Genghis Khan, founder of the Mongol Empire, as Timur had married Saray Mulk Khanum, a direct descendant of Genghis Khan.

The Mughal empire was a successor state to the Timurid empire and Babur himself was a direct descendant of Timur from his father's side. **But he was also a direct descendant of Genghis Khan from his mother's side.** So why did the Mughals adopt a name that essentially meant "in-laws of Ghengis Khan" when they were direct descendants of his?

Comment: I believe that Babur was not a direct descendant _as the Mongols reckon descent_  Why doesn't [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCrkan) answer the question?

Comment: How reliable is that etymology? E.g. Gürkhan is an actual Mongolian (though possibly not Mongol) royal title and sounds very similar. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurkhan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Altan Urugh (Golden Clan)**

Under steppe imperial tradition, only patrilineal descent from Chinggis Khan with his senior wife, Borte -- [male descendants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_and_descendants_of_Genghis_Khan) of Jochi, Chaghadai, Ögцdei and Tolui -- are entitled to this privilege (a member of the Golden Clan) and therefore  be considered for the position of emperor (supreme ruler, [*Qhagan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khagan)).

[Timur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timur) (1336-1405) is not considered a direct descendant of Chinggis Khan. His affinity with Chinggis Khan is shared ancestry, but not direct descent (from wikipedia). Their common ancestor was [Tumbinai Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumbinai_Khan). So, since Timur would never have been chosen as *Qhagan* by Mongol ruling council, or [*kurultai*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurultai), the most he could do was to claim "son-in-law" status by marrying important females of the Golden Clan.

This practice was not uncommon and many Mongol tribes with imperial ambitions in Central Asia tried to associate themselves with the revered Chinggis Khan in this manner. It was not solely restricted to Timur and his line, which includes [Babur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babur).

From *Nomadic Pathways in Social Evolution* (2003), pp.158-9:

> The most important decisions concerning the dynasty were resolved by
> congresses (*khurultais*) that served as an "an organ maintaining the
> state" in which the descendants of Chinggis Khan, as members of the
> ruling dynasty, played a decisive role. It was at such *khurultais* that
> the election of a new khan was officially proclaimed.
>
> During the 14th century, those Chinggisids living in western part of
> the Mongolian possessions in Eurasia had largely accepted Islam as
> their dominant religion. But at the same time "they considered the
> rights inherited from Chinggis Khan traditionally to be of more
> importance" because it was descent from "the Great Conqueror of a
> World" (and not religion) that in the eyes of their subjects
> legitimized their monopoly of the imperial throne. However, over time
> substantial real power to rule fell into the hands of their
> non-Chinggisid governors. These governors, who could not claim direct
> patrilineal descendant of Chinggis Khan on a man's line, often tried
> to elevate their social status by marrying Chinggisid princesses to
> gain the right to the title of "son-in-law" (*güregen*) to the khan’s
> family.
>
> The most famous example of this was Central Asian conquer Timur who in
> the beginning of his reign employed only the title of emir (leader).
> After the marrying a Chinggisid princesses he became a *güregen* and
> wielded immense power in the name of powerless puppet Chinggisid *khans*.

---

**Notes for context:**

1. On **steppe imperial tradition**: *Imperial Statecraft: Political Forms and Techniques of Governance in Inner Asia, 6th–20th Centuries* (2006), Chapter 1 - *The Türk Imperial Tradition In The Pre-Chinggisid Era* by Peter Golden (**[pdf](https://brill.com/previewpdf/book/edcoll/9789004216358/B9789004216358-s005.xml?pdfJsInlineViewToken=880291445&inlineView=true)**)
2. On **noble Mongol women** and their importance as part of the **Golden Clan (*Altan Urugh*)**:  *Cult of Alan-Gho'A and The Unique Position of Women in The Chinggisid Dyasties* (2017) (**[pdf](https://dergipark.org.tr/tr/download/article-file/621041)**)

Comment: But Babur was a direct descendant from his mother's side, wasn't he?

Comment: Babur may well have been born of a Golden clan mother but it would still not have allowed him to be selected in a ruling council because of the requirement for patrilineal/male-lines. In addition, Timur's line is known as the "Gurkani" (sons-in-law). This was a respected, though not to be confused with *legitimate*, imperial claim to rule. It would be foolish for anyone from Central Asia to ignore the *Gurkani* appellation. In most cases, it would it would be good enough given who Timur was. And as a direct descendant of Timur, Babur's use of the Gurkani was expected (in my opinion).